# Is this true about the open intervals on the real line?

Tags: analysis, geometry, elementary-number-theory, inequality, real-numbers

Let $a<b$ and let $m$ be a positive integer such that $$3^{-m} < \frac{b-a}{6}.$$ Then can we find a positive integer $k$ such that the open interval $$\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m}, \frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$$ is contained in the open interval $(a,b)$?

Comment: Not if $b < 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed true.

We are given that $ \dfrac{1}{3^m} \lt \dfrac{b - a}{6} $

Simly consider the set $A = \{ n \in \Bbb N \ |  \ a  \lt  \dfrac{n}{3^m}  \}$. The set $A$ is non-empty by the Archimedean Property.  Then $A$ has a minimum element $i$ by the Well-Ordering Principle.

Now, Suppose $b \le  \dfrac{ i + 5}{3^m}$ Then, $$  \dfrac{i - 1}{3^m} \ge b - \dfrac{6}{3^m} \gt b - \dfrac{6(b - a)}{6}  =  a  $$

This means that $(i - 1)\in A$ contradicting the minimality of  $i$. Hence we can arrive at, $$ a \lt \dfrac{i}{3^m} \lt \dfrac{i + 1}{3^m} \lt  \dfrac{i + 2}{3^m} \lt \dfrac{i + 3}{3^m} \lt \dfrac{i + 4}{3^m} \lt \dfrac{i + 5}{3^m} \lt b $$

Now every integer $n $ (or $i$ or $i + 1$ ...) takes one of the following forms $ 3k, 3k + 1, 3k + 2 $ for some integer $k$ by the Division Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Call $L(k)$ and $R(k)$ the left and right ends of the interval. You can find a $k$ with $0 < L(k)-a \leq 3^{-m+1}$.

Then 
$$b - R(k) = b - L(k) - 3^{-m} = b-a + a-L(k)-3^{-m} > 5\cdot 3^{-m} - 3^{-m+1} = 2\cdot 3^{-m} > 0$$
so $(a,b)$ encloses the interval.

Comment: user7530, how do we know that we can find a $k$ such that $0 < L(k) - a \leq 3^{-m+1}$?

Comment: Look at the gap $L(k+1)-L(k).$